# BlackJack Game Main Script Trouble (Classes Already Done)

Tags: python, object, object-oriented-analysis, blackjack, object-oriented-database

For my class project I am to make a BlackJack game that functions properly. It is a water-downed version of the game, (No Betting, Doubling Down , Splitting, etc...). We are to use different classes for the Deck, Hand and Card functions, which I did. The main trouble I am having is how to put it all together in a cohesive program so it can run. Here are my classes

```
class Card(object):

'''A simple playing card. A Card is characterized by two 
components:
rank: an integer value in the range 2-14, inclusive (Two-Ace)
suit: a character in 'cdhs' for clubs, diamonds, hearts, and
spades.'''

#------------------------------------------------------------

SUITS = 'cdhs'
SUIT_NAMES = ['Clubs', 'Diamonds', 'Hearts', 'Spades']

RANKS = range(2,15)
RANK_NAMES = ['Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six',
              'Seven', 'Eight', 'Nine', 'Ten', 
              'Jack', 'Queen', 'King', 'Ace']
RANK_VALUES = [99, 99, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11]
#------------------------------------------------------------

def __init__(self, rank, suit):

    '''Constructor
    pre: rank in range(1,14) and suit in 'cdhs'
    post: self has the given rank and suit'''

    self.rank_num = rank
    self.suit_char = suit


#------------------------------------------------------------

def getSuit(self):

    '''Card suit
    post: Returns the suit of self as a single character'''

    return self.suit_char

#------------------------------------------------------------

def getRank(self):

    '''Card rank
    post: Returns the rank of self as an int'''

    return self.rank_num

#------------------------------------------------------------

def getCardValue(self):
    value = self.RANK_VALUES[self.rank_num]
    return value

#------------------------------------------------------------
def suitName(self):

    '''Card suit name
    post: Returns one of ('clubs', 'diamonds', 'hearts',
          'spades') corrresponding to self's suit.'''

    index = self.SUITS.index(self.suit_char)
    return self.SUIT_NAMES[index]        

#------------------------------------------------------------

def rankName(self):

    '''Card rank name
    post: Returns one of ('ace', 'two', 'three', ..., 'king')
          corresponding to self's rank.'''

    index = self.RANKS.index(self.rank_num)
    return self.RANK_NAMES[index]

#------------------------------------------------------------

def __str__(self):

    '''String representation
    post: Returns string representing self, e.g. 'Ace of Spades' '''

    return self.rankName() + ' of ' + self.suitName()

#------------------------------------------------------------
from random import randrange
from Card import Card
from Hand import Hand


class Deck(object):
def __init__(self):
    '''This creates the deck of cards, un-shuffled.'''
    cards = []
    for suit in Card.SUITS:
        for rank in Card.RANKS:
            cards.append(Card(rank,suit))
    self.cards = cards

def size(self):
    '''How many cards are left.'''
    return len(self.cards)

def deal(self):
    '''Deals a single card.
    Pre: self.size() > 0
    Post: Returns the next card in self, and removes it from self.'''
    return self.cards.pop()

def shuffle(self):
    '''This shuffles the deck so that the cards are in random order.'''
    n = self.size()
    cards = self.cards
    for i,card in enumerate(cards):
        pos = randrange(i,n)
        cards[i] = cards[pos]
        cards[pos] = card

def takeAHit(self, whatHand):
    aCard = self.deal()
    whatHand.addCard(aCard)
def __str__(self):
    if self.size() == 52:
        return 'The Deck is Full'
    elif self.size() > 0:
        return 'The Deck has been Used'
    else:
        return 'The Deck is Empty'


from Card import Card
class Hand(object):

"""A labeled collection of cards that can be sorted"""

#------------------------------------------------------------

def __init__(self, label=""):

    """Create an empty collection with the given label."""

    self.label = label
    self.cards = []

#------------------------------------------------------------

def add(self, card):

    """ Add card to the hand """

    self.cards.append(card)

#------------------------------------------------------------

def totalHand(self):
    totalHand = 0
    aceAmount = 0

    for c in self.cards:
        if c.getRank() == 14:
            aceAmount += 1
            totalHand +=c.getCardValue()
    while aceAmount > 0:
        if totalHand > 21:
            aceAmount -= 1
            totalHand -= 10
        else:
            break
        return totalHand

def __str__(self):
    if self.cards == []:
        return "".join([(self.label), "doesn't have any cards."])
    tempStringList = [ self. label, "'s Cards,  "]
    for c in self.cards:
        tempStringList.append(str(c))
        tempStringList.append(" , ")

        tempStringList.pop()
        tempStringList.append(" . ")

        return "".join(tempStringList)
```

Now for the main function I need help on, my professor only helped me a little with part.

```
from Deck import Deck
from Card import Card
from Hand import Hand

def rules(playerTotal, dealerTotal):
if playerTotal > 21:
    print "You busted!"
    if dealerTotal == 21:
        print 'To make it worse, dealer has 21.'
elif dealerTotal > 21:
    print "The Dealer has busted. You win!"
elif playerTotal == 21:
    print " You got 21! So you win!"
    if dealerTotal == 21:
        print "The Dealer also got 21. Tough Break."
elif dealerTotal == 21:
    print "The Dealer got 21! Tough Break, you lose!"
else:
    if playerTotal > dealerTotal:
        print "You beat the Dealer! You got lucky punk."
    if playerTotal == dealerTotal:
        print "It is a push, no one wins!"
    else:
        print "Dealer wins! Better luck next time loser."
```

So I know I have to use the totalHand function from Hand to determine what the values are for playerTotal and dealerTotal, but everytime I try something I get this error.
    Player1 = raw_input("What is your name?")
    Dealer = "Dealer"
    twoCards = Hand(Player1)
    print twoCards.totalHand()

which prints out "none" and thats it..

If anyone can help me I would appreciated it, I'm kinda regretting my major choice as of now..

Comment: Please fix your indentation

Comment: in your code ... it looks likie you only return if you have aces

Answer (score 0):

In no particular order:

- Your shuffle is biased. Just use Python's random.shuffle(), it's correct and fast.
- totalHand is wrong (never adds non-aces to the value), and is way too complicated because you chose to use 11 as the value of aces, and doesn't report whether a total is hard or soft (which you need for proper play). Change the value of aces to 1, and simplify:

*

```
def totalHand(self):
    aceFound, isSoft = false, false
    total = 0

    for c in self.cards:
        total += c.getCardValue()
        if c.getCardValue() == 1:
            aceFound = true

    if aceFound and total < 12:
        total += 10
        isSoft = true

    return total, isSoft
```

- You can't base your results on just card totals. You have to play the hand in proper order:

  1. If dealer has natural, play is over. Players with natural push,
     all others lose.
  2. Each player in turn plays his hand. Naturals are paid off and
     removed, busts lose and are removed.
  3. Dealer plays his hand. If he busts, all remaining players win,
     otherwise players win/lose based on total.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I just have one more question, I'm sorry to bother you but any idea on how to make this run? Like when I say "Hit" a card is drawn? I'm really bad at object-orientation design. Would I do something like this?                                                                                                                    Player1 = raw_input("What is your name?")                                                 print Hand.totalHand(Player1)

Comment: Since it's just a learning assignment, then sure, interacting with raw_input is fine. But just insure that your main loop follows the outline above. To simplify, just have one player and no frills like splitting pairs (although double down and surrender aren't too hard).